# compareTo method logic to sort List by multiple variables

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparable

Problem : Create a standalone jar executable which will print the list of candidates appearing for the interview sorted order by name, age and experience ascending.

I am having trouble figuring out the compareTo method logic to be able to sort the 3 fields in the given problem.

Employee Class

```
package com.example.demo.employee;

public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

private String name;
private int age;
private int exp;

public Employee(String name, int age, int exp) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.exp = exp;
}

public Employee() {
}

// getter setter

@Override
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {

    // I do not think this logic is correct
    // I have read the other stack overflow posts with similar problem
    // but failing to under stand what to do in this method.

    int result = (this.name).compareTo(emp.name);
    if ( result == 0 ) {
        result = (this.age).compareTo(emp.age);
    }

    if ( result == 0 ) {
        result = (this.exp).compareTo(emp.exp);
    }
    return result;
 }

}
```

Employee Service Class

```
package com.example.demo.employee;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {


public List<Employee> getEmployees() {

    Employee e1 = new Employee("Sandhya", 20, 0);
    Employee e2 = new Employee("Kemp", 24, 2);
    Employee e3 = new Employee("Anil", 22, 3);
    Employee e4 = new Employee("Kumar", 30, 6);
    Employee e5 = new Employee("Tim", 32, 7);

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {

    List<Employee> eList = new ArrayList<>();
    eList.add(e1);
    eList.add(e2);
    eList.add(e3);
    eList.add(e4);
    eList.add(e5);

    Collections.sort(eList);

    return eList;
  }
}
```

EmployeeController

```
package com.example.demo.employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService es;

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public List<Employee> getEmpList(){
    List<Employee> list = es.getEmployees();
    return list;
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think the logic is wrong?  You may want to show a set of inputs, and what order you expect to result, and what does result from your code.  It seems like the data in your getEmployees() method would just sort by name, as none have the same name.

Comment: my IDE is giving me an error when I write that code for "age" and "exp", the error I get is "cannot resolve method compareTo(int)". The expected output is a list of candidates appearing for the interview sorted order by name, age and experience ascending

Comment: What version of java are you using?  As of Java 7, Integer has a compareTo method, and autoboxing of int to Integer was before that.   Maybe try `age.compareTo(emp.age)` without the unnecessary `(this.age)`

Comment: project version is java version 11.0.2. I changed it to "result = age.compareTo(emp.age);" and I still got the same error " cannot resolve compareTo(int)

Comment: Ya, I can see that... ok, new answer coming below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to implement `Comparable` and override the `compareTo` method, just use `Comparator`

```
Comparator<Employee> c = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName)
                                       .thenComparing(Employee::getAge)
                                       .thenComparing(Employee::getExp);
```

And the use `Collections.sort()` to sort the list using passed `Comparator`

```
Collections.sort(eList,c);
```

**By using Comparable**

The problem is `age` and `exp` are `int` type which is primitive were you cannot use `compareTo` method, change their type to `Integer` wrapper object or use `Integer.compare(int a, int b)` method

```
private int age;    // to private Integer age
private int exp;    // to private Integer exp
```

So that you can use `compareTo` on `age` and `exp`

```
this.getAge().compareTo(o.getAge());
this.getExp().compareTo(o.getExp());
```

If not look at my solution below using the `Integer.compare(int a, int b)`

**solution**

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {
    int result = this.getName().compareTo(o.getName());
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Integer.compare(this.getAge(), o.getAge());
        if (result == 0) {
            return Integer.compare(this.getExp(), o.getExp());
        }
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to call Integer.compare or String.compareTo twice?

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion of changing `int age` into `Integer age` just because some code doesn't compile. That's a very bad reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks really good, and I had to think a bit why it could be wrong at all.

The point is that the types `int` and `String` are very different in Java. `int` is a so-called primitive type (because it is not composed of other types), and `String` is an object type. By convention the names of primitive types start with a lowercase letter, while the names of object types start with a capital letter.

Only object types can have methods.

Since the type of `this.age` is `int` and thus a primitive type, `(this.age).compareTo(...)` is not allowed. Instead, you have to write `Integer.compare(this.age, emp.age)`.

The compiler's error message is not really helpful. Instead of saying "method int.compareTo not found", it should rather say "the type of this.age is int, and since that is a primitive type, no methods can be called on it".

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue seems to be that autoboxing isn't occurring in your compareTo, so you can either box them, or just deal with age/exp as primitive ints.
So do this, converting the primitive `int` to `Integer` that have compareTo:

```
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
    int result = (this.name).compareTo(emp.name);
    if ( result == 0 ) {
        result = Integer.valueOf(age).compareTo(emp.age);
    }
    if ( result == 0 ) {
        result = Integer.valueOf(exp).compareTo(emp.exp);
    }
    return result;
 }
```

alternately, you could do this, leaving the primitives alone:

```
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
    int result = (this.name).compareTo(emp.name);
    if ( result == 0 ) {
        result = Integer.compare( age, emp.age );
    }
    if ( result == 0 ) {
        result = Integer.compare( exp, emp.exp );
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int exp;
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getExp() {
        return exp;
    }
    public void setExp(int exp) {
        this.exp = exp;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Employee(String name, int age, int exp) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.exp = exp;
    }
    public Employee() {
  }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
    //replace your comparator here
       return (this.getAge() - emp.getAge());
  }

}
-------------------------------------------------------
@Service
public class EmployeeService {


    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Sandhya",20,0);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Kemp",24,2);
        Employee emp3 = new Employee("Anil",22,3);
        Employee emp4 = new Employee("Kumar",30,6);
        Employee emp5 = new Employee("Tim",32,7);
        emp.add(emp1);
        emp.add(emp2);
        emp.add(emp3);
        emp.add(emp4);
        emp.add(emp5);

        return emp;
    }




}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

  @Autowired
  EmployeeService employeeService;

  @RequestMapping("/")
    public List<Employee> getEmpList(){
    List<Employee> empController = employeeService.getEmployees();
    Collections.sort(empController);
        return empController;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The correct modifications to the code of your question of sorting is**

```
//In service class

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {

        Employee e1 = new Employee("Sandhya", 24, 0);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Kemp", 22, 2);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("Anil", 26, 3);
        Employee e4 = new Employee("Kumar", 30, 6);
        Employee e5 = new Employee("Tim", 32, 7);

        List<Employee> elist = Arrays.asList(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5);

        return elist;

//in controller class

@Autowired
    EmployeeService empserv;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public List<Employee> getEmpList(){
        List<Employee> list = empserv.getEmployees();
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }


//in Employee class, since it was asked to sort according to age of the employees

@Override

    public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        int result = Integer.compare(this.getAge(), o.getAge());;
        /*int result = this.getName().compareTo(o.getName());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = Integer.compare(this.getAge(), o.getAge());
            if (result == 0) {
                return Integer.compare(this.getExp(), o.getExp());
            }
            return result;
        }*/
    
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass this test.

In Employee class just add

public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
return this.getAge() - emp.getAge();

}

in EmployeeService Just copy the list data from TestEmployee class in getEmployess method and return list.

in EmployeeController add @RequestMapping("/") and use Collections.sort(list) and return list;